# How to get the label of the selected radio button in the event handler in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have the following codes,

```
for (i=0; i<answerArray.length; i++) {
    var myOptionButton1:spark.components.RadioButton = new spark.components.RadioButton();
    myOptionButton1.label = answerArray.getItemAt(i).Answer_Choice; 
    if (answerArray.getItemAt(i).Correct_Flag == 1) {               
        myOptionButton1.value = 1;
    } else {
            myOptionButton1.value = 0;
    }   

    answerItem.addChild(myOptionButton1);
    myOptionButton1.group = rbGroup;                        
    }
    rbGroup.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, selectionHandler);
}
```

rbGroup is the radio button group that holds the radio buttons together.  Usually, there would be four radio buttons in this radio button group.  In my selectionHandler function, for now, I am only trying to display the label of the selected radio button.  event.currentTarget.label seems to be only working for checkboxes.  Is there a way to get the label of the selected radio button?

Thanks in advance,
Monte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have look at the reference,

rbGroup.selection.label

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/RadioButtonGroup.html#selection

cheers,

Answer (score 0):

From [FlexExamples](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/06/21/detecting-when-a-radiobutton-has-been-clicked-in-a-radiobuttongroup-in-flex/):

You could add a listener for the `itemClick` event and access the `event.Label` property.

```
<mx:RadioButtonGroup id="radioGroup" itemClick="radioGroup_itemClick(event);" />

private function radioGroup_itemClick(evt:ItemClickEvent):void {
  trace(evt.label);
}
```